# Sending Mails with Queues in Larvael

Tags: php, laravel

First time using queue in laravel i have a simple contact form page that user submit information and i am trying to use queue to receive that information. I am pretty sure that my setup is incorrect because when i run the queue it saying processing. My question is how come my data isn't sending and what the correct way of sending the data in the array.

---

AskEmailController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Jobs\HelpEmailJob;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class AskEmailController extends Controller
{

    public function askemail()
    {
        return view('help.question');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {



                  HelpEmailJob::dispatch()
                 ->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5));
    }

}
```

---

HelpEmailJob

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use App\Mail\HelpEmailMailable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class HelpEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

    Mail::to('mikeshasaco@gmail.com')->queue(new HelpEmailMailable());
    }
}
```

---

HelpEmailMailiable

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class HelpEmailMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $data;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->$data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

            $data = array(
                'sirname' => $this->data['sirname'],
                'email' => $this->data['email'],
                'bodymessage' => $this->data['bodymessage'],
            );
        return $this->view('help.contactinfo')
        ->with([
            'data' =>$data,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel is this?

Comment: @TheFallen i am using laravel 5.5, so basically i have a form that submits to the store in the askemailcontroller am i suppose to store that data in the controller or in the mailable just a little confused

Comment: is the queue running?

Comment: @PhilCross yah i ran the queue command and the queue kept processing never processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly send the mail from your controller like this:

```
class AskEmailController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Mail::to('mikeshasaco@gmail.com')->send(new HelpEmailMailable);
    }
}
```

instead of using a job. And to make the email queue by default by implementing the `ShouldQueue` interface like this:

```
class HelpEmailMailable extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
  ...
}
```

Make sure your queue is running when you test this and always restart it after you make a change in the code.

Comment: So when i submit the form i get a error that say  `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\HelpEmailMailable::__construct() must be an instance of App\Mail\Data, array given, called in C:\wamp\www\newproject\app\Http\Controllers\AskEmailController.php on line 25` @theFallen